# PGSQL convert time to second

Tags: sql, postgresql

why i get error with this code

```
SELECT EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIME total_time) from tr_empl_quiz;
```

and i got error to with this code

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP total_time) from tr_empl_quiz;
```

this is my table content tr_empl_quiz and type data is time without time zone

```
total_time
============
00:01:00

00:02:00
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the `time` keyword?  Just `extract(second from total_time)` should do.

Comment: EXTRACT(SECOND FROM total_time) i get 0 value

ineed 60 and 120 second

Comment: but if i am hardcode like  this EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIME '00:01:00')  i get 60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `extract()` function you are getting the value of the *date/time part*.  In your examples, the seconds are zero, so that is what you get.

Postgres does support what you want, using the perhaps unintuitive name `epoch`.  `Epoch` returns the number of seconds.  For an date or datetime value, this is the number since 1970-01-01 (the beginning of Unix time).  For a `time` or `interval` it is the total number of seconds during the period.  So:

```
select extract(epoch from time '00:02:00')
```

returns 120.

Surprisingly, the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) for `epoch` doesn't mention that it works on the `time` data type.  The functionality is entirely consistent with what the function does.  Either the documentation (which is generally quite excellent) overlooks `time`; or `time` is treated as an `interval`.

For a column in a table, you would just do:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM total_time) 
FROM tr_empl_quiz;
```

or:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CAST(total_time as time)) 
FROM tr_empl_quiz;
```

Depending on what you want.

Comment: i am success for try
select extract(epoch from time '00:02:00')

but how if i set field from table